# Use trait as interface for database entity

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to make an `Entity` interface for dynamically mapping a database result into a Rust struct:

```
pub trait Entity {
    fn map(&self, Result<QueryResult>) -> Self;
}

pub struct DbQuery<T> {
    pub sql: String,
    pub params: Vec<Value>,
    pub limit: i32,
    pub paged: Option<Pagination>,
    pub entity: T,
}

pub struct Settings {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: Option<String>,
}

impl Entity for Settings {
    fn map(&self, result: Result<QueryResult>) -> Settings {
        // ...
        Settings {
            name: "hello".to_string(),
            value: None,
        }
    }
}

impl DbMapper {
    // ...

    pub fn find<T>(&self, query: DbQuery<T>) -> Option<Vec<T>> {
        println!("query find SQL: {}", query.sql);
        let mut stmt = &self.pool.prepare(query.sql).unwrap();
        let ret = Vec::new();
        for row in stmt.execute(query.params).unwrap() {
            ret.push(query.entity.map(row.unwrap()));

        }

        Some(ret)
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

> error: no method named `map` found for type `T` in the current scope
>   ret.push(query.entity.map(row.unwrap()));    |
>   note: the method `map` exists but the following trait
>   bounds were not satisfied: `T : std::iter::Iterator`    = help: items
>   from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope;
>   the following traits define an item `map`, perhaps you need to
>   implement one of them:    = help: candidate #1:
>   `models::holders::database::Entity`    = help: candidate #2:
>   `std::iter::Iterator`

Comment: Your example doesn't quite stand on its own as a minimal example, but I think the answer would be that you haven't constrained `T` to implement `Entity` in `DbQuery` and/or `DbMapper::find`.

Comment: Sorry, I've use the minimal code to explain it.
Unfortunately I've already tried with Entity instead of T but I receive the same error

Comment: Hi - it's somewhat minimal but it's not complete enough to put into play.rust-lang.org and try to compile it and get the same error, so it's a bit hard to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a version of your code that runs on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2edb1c01c9564ad8db00af04d848f2c7&version=stable&backtrace=0) and replicates your issue:

```
pub struct QueryResult;
pub struct Value;
pub struct Pagination;
pub struct DbMapper;

pub trait Entity {
    fn map(&self, Result<QueryResult, ()>) -> Self;
}

pub struct DbQuery<T> {
    pub sql: String,
    pub params: Vec<Value>,
    pub limit: i32,
    pub paged: Option<Pagination>,
    pub entity: T,
}

pub struct Settings {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: Option<String>,
}

impl Entity for Settings {
    fn map(&self, result: Result<QueryResult, ()>) -> Settings {
        // ...
        Settings {
            name: "hello".to_string(),
            value: None,
        }
    }
}

impl DbMapper {
    // ...

    pub fn find<T>(&self, query: DbQuery<T>) -> Option<Vec<T>> {
        println!("query find SQL: {}", query.sql);

        // ########## attempt to call map()
        let _ = query.entity.map(Ok(QueryResult {}));

        let ret = Vec::new();
        Some(ret)

    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The problem is that `T` in the `DbQuery<T>` argument in the `find` method has no idea that `T` is an `Entity` type. So we need to tell it:

```
pub fn find<T>(&self, query: DbQuery<T>) -> Option<Vec<T>>
    where T: Entity
{
    // ... code here ...
}
```

[This now compiles and runs](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7777c626c71589b4cadc8cb099473b1a&version=stable&backtrace=0).

The compiler now knows that `T` is an `Entity` of some description, and it can call the `map` method on it.

Comment: Yeah!!! ThankU very mutch. I'm a new bie on Rust.
But why not work with Entity instead of T?

Comment: Because `T` has no context in that method until you give it some explicitly. From the compilers perspective, you have said "Here is a type T... it could be any type". The compiler cannot know that the type implements a map method. By giving it a hint that it is an Entity type, the compiler knows that it can call map.